# how to install resolvconf in centos

Tags: centos, resolvconf

I'm trying to install resolvconf in centos.

In Ubuntu  I'm able to install  resolvconf `sudo apt-get install resolvconf`.

For centos, I tried to do the same by `sudo yum install resolvconf` but I get message `No package found. Nothing to do`

How can I install resolvconf in centos .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need `openresolv` and a patch. Follow these commands:

```
wget http://roy.marples.name/downloads/openresolv/openresolv-3.3.2.tar.bz2
tar fxjv openresolv-3.3.2.tar.bz2
cd openresolv-3.3.2
wget http://www.grid-appliance.org/files/packages/openresolv_patch.zip
unzip openresolv_patch.zip
make
./patch.sh
su -c "make install"
```

[Source](http://columbiabrian.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-install-resolvconf-on-linux.html)

Comment: the patch-link does not work anymore. Also does this work for centos 8?

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still trying to get this installed (especially if you are trying to install Mysterium VPN) — you can install the Fedora package on Rocky and CentOS:

```
wget https://download-ib01.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/36/Everything/aarch64/os/Packages/o/openresolv-3.12.0-3.fc36.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install openresolv-3.12.0-3.fc36.noarch.rpm
```

Now the Mysterium Desktop rpm (or any other w/OR as a dependency) should install without issue!

View all package and [get checksums here](https://pkgs.org/download/openresolv).

Comment: The MODGODS in all their infinite wisdom decided to edit my answer to embed the package/checksum page URI - for those of you on ELINKS, other CLI browsers, text browsers or text-to-speech clients - here you go: https://pkgs.org/download/openresolv